# Audio examples in phonetics project

Tags: pdf, audio

I am writing a project about phonetics and would ask if there is a way to include sound files directly in the PDF to be played directly in this file, preferably without any additional files having to be distributed along with the PDF.

I already know that it is possible to include media files in a PDF, but I would like it to be implemented as a short [image: loudspeaker]-like button<sup>1</sup> next to the word which, when clicked, plays the corresponding audio file (it needs to be this small, since I'm going to use **many** sound files in the same PDF).

I don't want any player or anything else to appear; the sound should just play quickly and smoothly, end of story, and clicking it again should give the same result. In fact, I would like it to function a bit like the sound file function on [this website](http://ordnet.dk/ddo/ordbog?query=udtryk&search=S%C3%B8g).

I do realize, of course, that maybe all of this is not even technically possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> Source: [ordnet.dk](http://ordnet.dk/ddo/speaker.gif).

Comment: Have you looked at the attachfile package.

Or is your question more focused on the actual technical playback functionality?

http://ftp.sun.ac.za/ftp/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile/attachfile.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have tested it a bit and looked through the manual, but it only appears to simply open external media players instead of simply playing the sound file within the PDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires Adobe Reader 9+ on Win or OSX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9,graphicx}

\begin{document}
Sound sample: \includemedia[
  addresource=sound_sample.mp3,
  transparent,
  flashvars={
    source=sound_sample.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  },
]{\includegraphics[height=1.44ex]{speaker.png}}{APlayer.swf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm currently installing Media9 to test it... I'm returning as soon as I've tested it. :-)

Comment: Works almost PERFECTLY!!! The only issue is that a small grey box appears when I hover over the icon with the mouse. But that is probably a limitation we don't get around, and it still functions exactly according to what I needed. THANKS A LOT!! :-D

Comment: But it appears not to work when linking to something in a parent folder. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: @Gaussler: The grey box is a progress bar indicating the current playhead position of the sound sample. Maybe the speaker icon is too small to produce a clickable link/progress bar of sufficient width.

Comment: @Gaussler: To include a media file in the parent folder, put `\addmediapath{..}` to the preamble.

Comment: That works :-D. But yes, the grey box is a player control device thing, and I assume that there's no way to hide it completely. But I suppose I can live with that. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler I could add a configuration FlashVar to APlayer.swf in the next version of media9, that allows the user to hide the user contol.

Comment: That would be really nice... and thanks again, it's an amazing package. :-)